# Order of initializing an equality C++

Tags: c++, function, class, constructor, initialization

This program does the addition of two integers, the program works perfectly (the exercise asks me to use constructor and past integers on it ). 
But on the constructor, if I initialize `num1 = nbre1` instead of `nbre1 = num1`the program doesn't work. 
Any explanation about the order ?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    class op{
        public :
            int nbre1, nbre2;
            op(int num1, int num2){
                nbre1=num1;
                nbre2=num2;
                std::cout<<"numbers initialized";
            }
            int add(){return nbre1+nbre2 ;}     
    };

    int n1;
    int n2;
    std::cout<<"Enter the first integer >> ";
    std::cin>>n1;
    std::cout<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"Enter the second integer >> ";
    std::cin>>n2;

    op addition(n1,n2);
    std::cout<<"The sum of the two numbers is >> " << addition.add();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whar do you expect `num1 = nbre1` to do?

Comment: @NathanOliver past the initialized integers of the class inside the constructor.

Comment: To touch on Nathan Oliver's point from another direction, what would you expect of `10 + 1 = x;`?

Comment: Totally unrelated but useful bit of functionality that rarely seems to be taught in school: `op(int num1, int num2): nbre1(num1), nbre2(num2){ std::cout<<"numbers initialized"; }`. This is using [the Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). It becomes very important later when classes get more complicated. For example it answers the question, How do I pass the arguments to the `op` constructor when another class contains an `op`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The C++ assignment operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_(C%2B%2B)) `=` sets the left hand value equal to the right hand value. The statement `num1 = nbre1` sets num1 to be the uninitialized value in nbre1. If nbre1 was previously initialized, the statement sets num1 to that value but since num1 isn't being used anywhere else in that function, it essentially does nothing.